# How to get the second `then` callback parameter with async/await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

For example

```
randomLibPromise.then((data, err) => { // do something with err })
```

how would I translate that with await?
This promise comes from a library so I don't have control over the fact that the error goes through `then` instead of `catch`. What I have is:

```
let data = await randomLibPromise.catch(err)
```

but I don't get that second parameter and I can't retrieve the error.

Every example I find on Google talk about `catch` for error handling but not `then`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "fix" the weird promise, you could just `throw err` if there is one, and `return` the data otherwise:

```
var fixed = randomLibPromise.then((data, err) => { 
    if(err) throw err;
    return data;
})
```

The result will be a promise which does the correct thing, i.e. passes the data to a `then`, an error to a `catch` or, if awaiting, either returns `data` or throws the error.

```
fixed.then(data => { /* handle data */ }).catch(err => { /* handle err */ });
// or
try {
    var data = await fixed;
    // handle data
} catch(err) {
    //handle err
}
```